# error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::exception'

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk

I'm building a .so file with android NDK from jsoncpp.git, but compiling, I have some problems, hope someone can help me!

````
   (1/2) gnustl -> already built]
           -----> Contents of /cerbero/cerbero/build/logs/android_arm64/jsoncpp-extract.log:
           -----> Extracting tarball to /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir
           Unpacking /root/.cache/cerbero-sources/jsoncpp-1.6.4/1.6.4.tar.gz in 
          /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64
          Running command ['git', 'init']
          Reinitialized existing Git repository in /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/.git/
          Running command ['git', 'config', 'user.email']
          Running command ['git', 'config', 'user.email', 'cerbero@gstreamer.freedesktop.org']
          Running command ['git', 'config', 'user.name']
          Running command ['git', 'config', 'user.name', 'Cerbero Build System']
          Running command ['git', 'add', '--force', '-A', '.']
          Running command ['git', 'diff', '--quiet', 'HEAD']
  

  ```
    -----> Contents of /cerbero/cerbero/build/logs/android_arm64/jsoncpp-configure.log:
    Running command 'cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64 -H/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4 -B/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH=/cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR=bin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=include -DJSONCPP_WITH_TESTS:bool=OFF-DJSONCPP_WITH_POST_BUILD_UNITTEST:bool=OFF -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ '-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-target aarch64-none-linux-android --sysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -gcc-toolchain /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -isysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -fno-integrated-as -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIC -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -DANDROID -DPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -g -Os ' '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-nostdlib++ -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../llvm-libc++abi/include -target aarch64-none-linux-android --sysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -gcc-toolchain /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -isysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -fno-integrated-as -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIC -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -DANDROID -DPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21  -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions  -Wall -g -Os  -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive' -DLIB_SUFFIX= -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release '-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$CERBERO_PREFIX' -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE:BOOL=true'
    -- The C compiler identification is Clang 9.0.8
    -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 9.0.8
    -- Check for working C compiler: /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
    -- Check for working C compiler: /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- JsonCpp Version: 1.6.3
    -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.6")
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    CMake Warning:
      Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
    
        CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR
        CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR
        CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR
        CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH
    
    
    -- Build files have been written to: /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir
    
    -----> Contents of /cerbero/cerbero/build/logs/android_arm64/jsoncpp-compile.log:
    Running command 'make V=1 VERBOSE=1'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/build-tools/bin/cmake -S/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4 -B/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/build-tools/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/CMakeFiles /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    make[1]: Entering directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    make -f src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/build.make src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/depend
    make[2]: Entering directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir && /cerbero/cerbero/build/build-tools/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4 /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/lib_json /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
    Dependee "/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/depend.internal".
    Dependee "/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/depend.internal".
    Scanning dependencies of target jsoncpp_lib_static
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    make -f src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/build.make src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/build
    make[2]: Entering directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    [ 11%] Building CXX object src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_reader.cpp.o
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json && /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++   -I/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/include -I/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/lib_json/../../include  -nostdlib++ -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../llvm-libc++abi/include -target aarch64-none-linux-android --sysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -gcc-toolchain /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -isysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -fno-integrated-as -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIC -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -DANDROID -DPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21  -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions  -Wall -g -Os  -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -o CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_reader.cpp.o -c /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp
    [ 22%] Building CXX object src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_value.cpp.o
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json && /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++   -I/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/include -I/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/lib_json/../../include  -nostdlib++ -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../llvm-libc++abi/include -target aarch64-none-linux-android --sysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -gcc-toolchain /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -isysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -fno-integrated-as -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIC -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -DANDROID -DPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21  -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions  -Wall -g -Os  -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -o CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_value.cpp.o -c /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/lib_json/json_value.cpp
    [ 33%] Building CXX object src/lib_json/CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json && /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++   -I/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/include -I/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/lib_json/../../include  -nostdlib++ -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../llvm-libc++abi/include -target aarch64-none-linux-android --sysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -gcc-toolchain /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -isysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -fno-integrated-as -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIC -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -DANDROID -DPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21  -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions  -Wall -g -Os  -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -o CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_writer.cpp.o -c /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/lib_json/json_writer.cpp
    [ 44%] Linking CXX static library libkmsjsoncpp.a
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json && /cerbero/cerbero/build/build-tools/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/lib_json && /cerbero/cerbero/build/build-tools/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/ar qc libkmsjsoncpp.a  CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_reader.cpp.o CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_value.cpp.o CMakeFiles/jsoncpp_lib_static.dir/json_writer.cpp.o
    /usr/bin/ranlib libkmsjsoncpp.a
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    [ 44%] Built target jsoncpp_lib_static
    make -f src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/build.make src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/depend
    make[2]: Entering directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir && /cerbero/cerbero/build/build-tools/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4 /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/jsontestrunner /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/jsontestrunner /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
    Dependee "/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/depend.internal".
    Dependee "/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/depend.internal".
    Scanning dependencies of target jsontestrunner_exe
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    make -f src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/build.make src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/build
    make[2]: Entering directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    [ 55%] Building CXX object src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/main.cpp.o
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/jsontestrunner && /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++   -I/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/include -I/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/lib_json/../../include  -nostdlib++ -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../llvm-libc++abi/include -target aarch64-none-linux-android --sysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -gcc-toolchain /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -isysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -fno-integrated-as -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIC -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -DANDROID -DPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21  -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions  -Wall -g -Os  -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/main.cpp.o -c /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/jsontestrunner/main.cpp
    [ 66%] Linking CXX executable jsontestrunner_exe
    cd /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir/src/jsontestrunner && /cerbero/cerbero/build/build-tools/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  -nostdlib++ -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../llvm-libc++abi/include -target aarch64-none-linux-android --sysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -gcc-toolchain /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -isysroot /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include -isystem /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -fno-integrated-as -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fPIC -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -DANDROID -DPIC -D__ANDROID_API__=21  -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions  -Wall -g -Os  -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG  -gcc-toolchain /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -fPIC -no-canonical-prefixes -Wl,-no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -L/cerbero/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64/lib -L/cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/lib  -fuse-ld=gold  -nostdlib++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/main.cpp.o  -o jsontestrunner_exe  ../lib_json/libkmsjsoncpp.a
    CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/main.cpp.o(.data+0x0): error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::exception'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/new:253: error: undefined reference to 'operator new(unsigned long)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/new:334: error: undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/new:253: error: undefined reference to 'operator new(unsigned long)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/new:334: error: undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/new:253: error: undefined reference to 'operator new(unsigned long)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/new:334: error: undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/new:253: error: undefined reference to 'operator new(unsigned long)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/new:334: error: undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/jsontestrunner/main.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'operator new[](unsigned long)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/jsontestrunner/main.cpp:68: error: undefined reference to 'operator delete[](void*)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/jsontestrunner/main.cpp:320: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_begin_catch'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/jsontestrunner/main.cpp:324: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_catch'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:711: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::init(void*)'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:232: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::locale()'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:307: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::~locale()'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/iosfwd:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::~ios_base()'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/src/jsontestrunner/main.cpp:183: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::~ios_base()'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:307: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::~locale()'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:307: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::~ios_base()'
    ....
    ../lib_json/libkmsjsoncpp.a(json_writer.cpp.o):json_writer.cpp:vtable for Json::StreamWriter: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_pure_virtual'
    ../lib_json/libkmsjsoncpp.a(json_writer.cpp.o):json_writer.cpp:typeinfo for Json::Writer: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
    /cerbero/cerbero/build/android-ndk-21/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
    ../lib_json/libkmsjsoncpp.a(json_writer.cpp.o):json_writer.cpp:vtable for Json::Writer: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_pure_virtual'
    ../lib_json/libkmsjsoncpp.a(json_writer.cpp.o):json_writer.cpp:vtable for Json::StreamWriter::Factory: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_pure_virtual'
    clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target 'src/jsontestrunner/jsontestrunner_exe' failed
    make[2]: *** [src/jsontestrunner/jsontestrunner_exe] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:203: recipe for target 'src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [src/jsontestrunner/CMakeFiles/jsontestrunner_exe.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/cerbero/cerbero/build/sources/android_arm64/jsoncpp-1.6.4/_builddir'
    Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    

    Recipe 'jsoncpp' failed at the build step 'compile'
    Command Error: Running ['make', 'V=1', 'VERBOSE=1'] returned 2
    Output in logfile /cerbero/cerbero/build/logs/android_arm64/jsoncpp-compile.log
   '''
````

Who can tell me what wrong with my compile project?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that test is compiled with `-nostdlib++` but then no actual libc++ is linked in its place.

Comment: thank you! test is not use gnustl ? i don't know how set?

Comment: Probably patch the jsoncpp build system to include whatever STL you're trying to force?

Comment: LDFLAGS is use 'gnustl',I think LDFLAGS is not find 'gnustl',do you know i can add "LDFLAGS=?"?

Comment: From the printed command line it does not look like the jsoncpp test build configuration picked up your LDFLAGS. You should probably investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build jsoncpp, that's available as an AAR: https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/d191bf0cb3e1046c9fe15323d3a986862c0e2233/prefab/prefab-dependency/app/build.gradle#L67